# Prisma is returning null in Next 13.4 but works in node ts

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, next.js, prisma

**Question Summery**: Prisma Client is not working in Next 13.4 api routes or components. But when I run the same function in node-ts file it works perfectly. (They share the same client instance, and database)

[Repo Link](https://github.com/Re9iNee/Mora-Website/commit/d1f97d138a015ce5db7b46853e7da3d32480d566)

When I try to search in DB I get `null` from prisma client. but when I run prisma seed file everything is ok.

I use the same instance in both next and seed file.

`/prisma/seed.ts`

```js
async function getBySlug() {
  const ai = await prisma.aI.findUnique({ where: { slug: "Dua-Lipa" } });

  return ai;
}

getBySlug()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
  .finally(() => prisma.$disconnect());
```

NextJS component:

`/src/ai/[slug]/page.tsx`

```js
import { prisma } from "@/lib/prisma";

type Props = {
  params: { slug: string };
};
async function getAiBySlug(slug: string) {
  const ai = await prisma.aI.findUnique({ where: { slug: "Dua-Lipa" } });

  console.log("ai ->", ai);
  return ai;
}

const AiSlug = async ({ params }: Props) => {
  const ai = await getAiBySlug(slug);


  return (
    <div>
      AiSlug, request to visit: <pre>{params.slug}</pre>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(ai)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AiSlug;
```

I'm using Mongodb, Prisma, Prisma Client, Next 13.4 and typescript.

I've tried prisma functions like: `findUnique`, `findUniqueOrThrow`.

`findFirst`, `findMany` works until I add `where` clause. and it will throw an error.

---

1. The spelling is correct and works on seed file.
2. Schema file for slug property is `@unique`.
3. Both `seed.ts` and `page.tsx` are using the same instance of `PrismaClient`

---

This is how I run seed file:

```
ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts
```

Could this be about my Typescript? let me know if I needs to add `tsconfig` file

Could this be about my next.config file? (It's empty)
Could this be about nextAuth? (Just asking)

Comment: `null` means there is no record with this slug. double-check your db. or run `npx prisma studio`

Comment: Like I said, the record does exist when I run it in ts-node folder (seed.tsx), it only returns null on page server components. @AhmedAbdelbaset

Comment: Can you share a repo?

Comment: https://github.com/Re9iNee/Mora-Website/commit/d1f97d138a015ce5db7b46853e7da3d32480d566

@AhmedAbdelbaset